# Why do I get this error when creating an Intent and haw to pass data from Firebase that is in RecyclerView on second screen

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I marked the parts that were added (added to code) after the moment
when the application was working, the data was successfully downloaded
from the database. I may be mistakenly trying to pass this information
to another screen. I tried to find a video that connects to the
database and forwards that data of recicler on another screen, but
without success, or they are in Java, which I understand less.

### MySecondActivity

```
 class BookDescription : AppCompatActivity() {
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_description)
 
        var books = intent.getSerializableExtra("noti") as Book //added to code
 
         Glide.with(this).load(books.imageUrl).into(bookImg2)// added to code
         nameTxt2.text = books.name //added to code
         autorTxt2.text = books.writer  //added to code
     } 
}
```

### MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private lateinit var adapter : Adapter
    private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)}
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setUpRecyclerView()
    }

    private fun setUpRecyclerView(){
        adapter = Adapter(this){
            startBookDescription()
        }
        recycle.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
        recycle.adapter = adapter
        observerData()
    }

       fun observerData(){
           viewModel.fetchUserData().observe(this,Observer{
               adapter.setListdata(it)
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
           })
       }

    private fun startBookDescription(){
        val intent = Intent (this, BookDescription::class.java )
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

### Class Adapter with inner class Holder

```
class Adapter(private val context: Context,
              private val onItemCliked: () -> Unit ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.Holder>() {

    private var datalist = mutableListOf<Book>()
    fun setListdata(data: MutableList<Book>){
        datalist = data
    }

    inner class Holder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
         fun bindView(book: Book, onItemClicked: () -> Unit){
             Glide.with(context).load(book.imageUrl).into(itemView.bookImg)
             itemView.nameTxt.text = book.name
             itemView.autorTxt.text= book.writer
             itemView.setOnClickListener { onItemClicked.invoke() }

            itemView.bookImg.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { //added
            val intent = Intent(context, BookDescription::class.java)//added to code
                 intent.putExtra("noti", book)//added to code
                 context.startActivity(intent)//added to code
             })
         }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.book_format, parent,
false )
        return Holder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
           val book = datalist[position]
           holder.bindView(book, onItemCliked)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return if (datalist.size> 0){
            datalist.size
        }else{
            0
        }
    } 
}
```

[image: Error message]

Comment: Please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to include the exact error message and stack trace you get.

Comment: I'm really trying to add the rest of the code with an error but I'm constantly getting the error that I don't have enough content. I posted the picture I added an image with an error. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: That error is shown for a good reason, as your question is indeed rather light on details. Showing the error message as text helps for that, but then don't mark it as code, but as a block quite (with `>` at the start of each line).

Comment: Successfully added the rest of the code thanks to you are a real life saver. I really appreciate your effort I search the internet for days to solve this. @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

> ```
> intent.putExtra("noti", book)
> ```

The `book` variable is of type `Book`, which is apparently neither a `Parcelable` or `Serializable` class. You must implement one of these two interfaces in the `Book` class in order to add it to an `Intent` or `Bundle`.

Assuming `Book` is made up of simple data types (`String`, `Int`, etc), then you can use the `@Parcelize` annotation to easily implement `Parcelable`. More here: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize

---

In your `bindView()` method, you have this block of code:

> ```
> val intent = Intent(context, BookDescription::class.java)//added to code
>     intent.putExtra("noti", book)//added to code
>     context.startActivity(intent)//added to code
> })
> ```

However, you don't actually do anything with this `Intent`; you start your activity from another place:

> ```
> private fun startBookDescription(){
>     val intent = Intent (this, BookDescription::class.java )
>     startActivity(intent)
> }
> ```

You will have to pass the `Book` instance to this method (via `invoke(book)`). This will require a corresponding type change to the click listener parameter of your adapter.

Comment: The error has disappeared thanks to your help, but the data is still not transferred to another screen. Do you know what the problem is with my code? App is conected to Firebase.

Comment: I am rude if I ask for a little more clarification, I am a student and a beginner in this. Please @Ben P.

Comment: There may be an easier way to transfer this data, I'm confused right now... :(